# Does ptr::write() make a new object?

Tags: rust

This is the code:

```
struct Foo {}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("drop");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(1);
    let foo = Foo {};
    v.push(foo);
}
```

It prints "drop" only once. However, looking into the implementation of `push()` I see this line:

```
ptr::write(end, value);
```

The `value` (which is `foo`) is written into memory. As far as I understand, a *binary copy* of `foo` is created when this writing is happening. Thus, a new struct is created. Thus, another `drop()` should be called when memory is freed. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: A moved value isn't dropped, it's moved. The memory isn't necessarily freed, either, as this could be stack-allocated, or even optimized away. I like to think of the value as being "teleported" to the new location. The old location is just empty space at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptr::write` purposely does not drop the copied value. You can see that happen [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.69.0/src/core/ptr/mod.rs.html#1355), where the original value is [forgotten](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.forget.html) instead of dropped:

```rs
copy_nonoverlapping(&src as *const T, dst, 1);
intrinsics::forget(src)
```

(The link is to `mem::forget` instead of `intrinsics::forget` because it explains better what "forget" means in rust)

Whether something compiles to a binary copy or not is unrelated to whether something is dropped or not. Drops only happen when a value reaches the end of its scope. Non-`Copy` types will only ever be dropped once unless they are explicitly cloned or remade. In this case, `forget` stops that from happening in `push`, and instead, the value is dropped by `Vec`'s implementation of `Drop` when the `Vec` reaches the end of its scope.

For most situations, you don't need to worry about the implementation of `Vec`. The implementation is merely ensuring that soundness is maintained, despite `Vec` being implemented with pointers.